# How to select multiple selected value from select option

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, ionic-framework

My controller code looks like

```
$scope.items = [{
    heading: 'Sports',
    types: [{
        name: 'Football',
    }, {
        name: 'Persie',
    }, {
        name: 'Ronaldo',
    }, {
        name: 'Messy',
    }],
    id: '1'
}, {
    heading: 'Cricket',
    types: [{
        name: 'Tendulkar',
    }, {
        name: 'Lara',
    }, {
        name: 'Ponting',
    }],
    id: '2'
}];
```

My view contains something like this : 
    
     

How can I get the selected values of options when user clicks submit button

Comment: What is `searchOption` rendering when displaying it and changing option  values?

Comment: ng-model will be set to the selected item

Comment: I'm still not able to view it in myCtrl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/g8dw6akj/5) 
I used ng-repeat to build the select and ng-options to fill them, you then have to use the relative ng-model to get the selections.

HTML:

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <select class="select fancy" ng-repeat="(i, item) in items" ng-model="searchOption[i]" ng-options="type.name for type in item.types"></select>
  <button ng-click="submitIt()">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.submitIt = function () {
        console.log($scope.searchOption);
    };

    $scope.searchOption = [];

    $scope.items = [{
            heading: 'Sports',
            types: [{
                name: 'Football',
    }, {
                name: 'Persie',
    }, {
                name: 'Ronaldo',
    }, {
                name: 'Messy',
    }],
            id: '1'
  }, {
            heading: 'Cricket',
            types: [{
                name: 'Tendulkar',
    }, {
                name: 'Lara',
    }, {
                name: 'Ponting',
    }],
            id: '2'
  }];
}
```

Comment: There are 2 option boxes not 1 , and I want the selected value of both

Comment: So you should write better your code, where is the other select? Do you use ng-repat over `$scope.items`?

Comment: For each heading I have an option with corresponding types as option values nad I'm using ng-repeat above this div

Comment: Updated the answer please look at it

Comment: Rock Solid :) Thanks a lot

Comment: How can I access the value of search option in MyCtrl

Comment: I'm away let me come back home I will update the fiddle

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81211/discussion-between-michelem-and-ecko123).